# Shell script wildcard expansion issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Following is my shell script and I try to copy all the files in the current directory to another machine which I have permission to copy.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp -pr "*" root@192.168.1.2:/home/user1/.
expect {
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "user1user1\r"
}
}
interact
```

And, I receive the following error when try to run this script. The wildcard * is not working as expected.

```
spawn scp -pr * root@192.168.1.2:/home/user1/.
root@192.168.1.2's password: 
*: No such file or directory
Killed by signal 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"[glob {*}]"` instead of `"*"`, *Expect* speaks *TCL*.